# ARM-based Emulator for Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to create an emulator for Oreo (Android 8) that runs ARM AEBI V7. The reason I need this architecture is that I include a component that has a native library, but compiled only for armaebi-v7. I do not have access to the source code for the component so I can't recompile the native code.

In Android Studio, when I open the SDK Manager and expand the options for Oreo, I see an emulator image for X86 only. For earlier versions of Android I can see ARM emulator images.

Should I see ARM images for Oreo as well? Or perhaps these have not been released yet?

Answer (score 1):

It is still the same. Let's hope that they will add. I use the x86 build for the android 8 emulator, which is built separately, specifically for this purpose.